# .ready fires too soon in iframe when sharing jQuery instance

Tags: jquery, iframe, ready

I am wanting to avoid loading a seperate instance of jQuery in each of many iframes.  For the most part this is working well.  The problem I'm having is with the ready event.  It does not seem to work properly within the child iframe.

`parent.$(document).ready(function () {
        // this fires before the DOM is ready.
    });`

using window.onload works, but fires late in the game.  Is it possible to get a proper 'ready' event triggered within an iframe without loading a seperate instance of jQuery ?